# Heel up technique

Tags: drums, bass-drum

I want to know the muscle groups which are used in performing heel-up technique and how they are used. This is to know if I am doing it correct.
While striking shall I use my hip muscles to lift my leg up and then use my ankle (which will use shin and calf muscles) to strike. Or shall I just rest my weight of legs on the pedal and just use calf muscles to bounce my leg in the air which will ultimately come down performing 1 strike.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to your own preference, but I have never seen a drummer solely use his ankle to strike the kick drum. This seems rather exhausting to me.

I mainly use the muscles of my upper leg to lift the leg. Then I use a combination of my ankle muscles + upper leg muscles to hit the kick drum. Between strokes I rest my legs on the pedals.

[YourMusicMuse](https://youtu.be/fHy5JTTmMm0?t=78) has a good video of this technique.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right" answer. You can use both techniques you mentioned, depending on the end goal. Playing with a whole leg vs foot-only can create a huge difference in dynamics, i.e. accents. Also, playing successive fast notes usually requires a combination of both types of strokes.

I've collected a few tips on my [bass drum page](http://music.alensiljak.ml/drums/bass), including useful videos from a former death metal drummer Marthyn Jovanovic. I find them quite useful even though I'm mostly interested in playing jazz.

The combination of strokes is best described in Jojo Mayer's foot technique. One interpretation you can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8xUmAd0kT8). It is good to practice exaggerating the moves, just so that the movement sinks in.